# Going from an list to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, linked-list

So I'm working on a problem and I successfully solved the first part, which allowed me to add some types to an object as here

```
function arrayToList(array) {
  var list = null;
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
  return list;
}
```

Now this works fine and all, but now I'm trying to make another function concurrently which does the opposite. The solution is here

```
function listToArray(list) {
  var array = [];
  for (var node = list; node; node = node.rest)
    array.push(node.value);
  return array;
}
```

Could someone please explain how this for loop works? I don't understand the structure of this for loop and I looked on w3 schools for an example similar to this. Why is the second parameter of the for loop a variable? Also why is the third parameter equating our variable to a type?

Comment: Note that the definition of a for loop is as follows: `for (declaration; condition; modification)` So in the second example, `node` is the condition for the loop to continue. It will continue as long as `node` is defined. And the modification simply sets the node to the next item, node.rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

[For loops contain 3 statements in their body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for):

```
for (initialization; condition; final-expression)
```

I think you understand how `initialization` and `final-expression` work, but the `condition` is the test that determines whether the for loop continues iterating or terminates.

Since `node` can be an object or `null` in this case, those are "truthy" and "falsy" values. `Boolean(null) === false`, so if the current iteration has landed on a `null`, it knows that the linked list has ended and it can stop looping.

### Walkthrough

Alright, so the reason why the second for loop starts with `node = list` is because `list` is an `object` that needs to be traversed. Notice that the next `node` is always contained in `node.rest`. So in order to "increment", we need to assign `node.rest` to `node` using `node = node.rest`. Now we understand these parts:

```
for (var node = list; ... ; node = node.rest)
```

The remaining part is the statement that checks whether the for loop should continue or terminate. We know that if `node` is `null`, then there are no more nodes left to traverse, so we can check that. In JavaScript, since `Boolean(null) === false`, we can simply assert that `node` is "truthy" to contiunue, since `Boolean({}) === true`. So the statement `node` just checks whether to continue or not:

```
for (var node = list; node; node = node.rest)
```

### Demo

One of the most informative things to do when learning a language construct is to run the code and see what the output looks like yourself. In this example, the `array` is

```
["hello", "world", "how", "are", "you", "today"]
```

and the `list` is

```
{"value": "hello", "rest": {"value": "world", "rest": {"value": "how", "rest": {"value": "are", "rest": {"value": "you", "rest": {"value": "today", "rest": null}}}}}}
```

```js
/* ignore this */
console.log = function (data) {
  if (typeof data === 'object') {
    data = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
  }
  
  document.write('<pre>' + data + '</pre>');
}

/* pay attention to everything below here */
function arrayToList(array) {
  console.log('arrayToList\n\n');

  var list = null;
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
    console.log('index: ' + i);
    console.log('value: ' + JSON.stringify(array[i]));
    console.log(list);
    console.log('-----');
  }
  
  return list;
}

function listToArray(list) {
  console.log('listToArray\n\n');

  var array = [];
  for (var node = list; node; node = node.rest) {
    array.push(node.value);
    console.log('index: ' + (array.length - 1));
    console.log('value: ' + JSON.stringify(array.slice(-1)[0]));
    console.log(node);
    console.log('-----');
  }

  return array;
}

var array = ['hello', 'world', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'today'];

var list = arrayToList(array);

listToArray(list);
```

```css
pre {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I get how the for loop works now. But the logic is still confusing me. What exactly is the var node = list initialization trying to even say?  Commonly we say i = 0 as the initialization, to give a variable a start value. So why is our start value "list" here?

Comment: Could you perhaps explain step by step what happens every iteration?

Comment: Ok I think I get it now, so while we are in node, which is initlaized to list. set node equal to node.rest, as long as we are IN the node. If we are in the node put the value of this node into an array. However I am still unsure of what the objective of setting node = node.rest is.

Comment: Wow. Amazing walk through explanation. Thanks so much.. this is some deep stuff right here.

Comment: Completed it on my own without looking at the solution.Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

In the first statement of the for, you are assigning the node variable to list. This is the initial value it will hold when running on the first iteration. Then the second statement is a condition, if it is true/not empty, it will continue to execute the for loop. The third statement you are reassigning the node variable to node.rest, which would make the second statement change for the next loop. The loop will exit when the node variable is an empty value.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the actual syntax of a for loop now, but am confused  as to why I am doing this. WHY am i setting node to list? why do I want to set node = node.rest? and why am i inserting node.value inside the array every iteration?